# Can you link to a search in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm going through a process of creating documentation from a long list of emails.  This process is ongoing and I don't have control of the input (the fact that the source is coming via email).  The documentation I am creating links to (or contains) the information from the emails.

What I've been doing is exporting the email thread to html, making available on our intranet and then linking to it in my documentation.  Sometimes new emails in the same thread come in after I create the link thus causing problems.  Also, it'd be ideal to keep the privacy of these emails and not have to repost the content.  Also, it'd be easier for me if I didn't have to export them to html.

What would be ideal is to be able to create a link to the user's own outlook email (something like `outlook://search:subject:"howto create blue widgets"`).  This obviously assumes the user has that email thread in their inbox.  Can I do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You're using Outlook 2013 and it lacks such kind of functionality. With Outlook 2010/2007 you were be able to search right from Windows explorer by using special kind of URL (search-ms: protocol). In Outlook 2013 Microsoft removed this feature for some reason.